# AWS credentials missing when running userdata in a new EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform, cloud, aws-policies

Using terraform scripts, I create a new EC2, add policy to access an S3 bucket, and supply a userdata script that runs `aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/file-name .` to copy a file from that S3 bucket, among other commands.

In `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` I see `fatal error: Unable to locate credentials`, presumably caused by executing `aws s3 cp ...` line. When I execute the same command manually on the EC2 after it's been created, it works fine (which means the EC2 policy for bucket access is correct).

Any ideas why the `aws s3 cp` command doesn't work during `userdata` execution but works when the EC2 is already created? Could it be that the S3 access policy is only applied to the EC2 after the EC2 has been fully created (and after `userdata` has been run)? What should be the correct workaround?

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_assume_role" {

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole",
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "ec2.amazonaws.com",
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "broker" {
  name                  = "${var.env}-broker-role"
  assume_role_policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2_assume_role.json
  force_detach_policies = true
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "broker_instance_profile" {
  name = "${var.env}-broker-instance-profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.broker.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "rabbitmq_ec2_access_to_s3_distro" {
 name = "${env}-rabbitmq_ec2_access_to_s3_distro"
 role = aws_iam_role.broker.id
 policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.rabbitmq_ec2_access_to_s3_distro.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "rabbitmq_ec2_access_to_s3_distro" {
 statement {
   effect = "Allow"
   actions = [
     "s3:GetObject",
     "s3:GetObjectVersion"
   ]
   resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::${var.distro_bucket}", "arn:aws:s3:::${var.distro_bucket}/*"]
 }
}


resource "aws_instance" "rabbitmq_instance" {
  iam_instance_profile   = ${aws_iam_instance_profile.broker_instance_profile.name}
  ....
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say without your terraform config provided, however what permissions are on the EC2 Instance / what Role do you have attached? You should be allowing the EC2 Instance to access S3 as well & credentials shouldn't be needed with the correct Instance Role / Profile.

Comment: @paulg that is exactly what I do - i have a policy that allows EC2 to access the S3 bucket, and I don't use any additional credentials, it's a ll role based access. And as I said, it works when I ssh into the EC2 and run `aws s3 cp`, so the policy is correct.
I updated my question with the relevant excerpt from terraform script

Comment: in your example there is a typo: `aws s3 cp s://bucket-name/file-name` should be `aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/file-name` - not sure if that's actually your issue or just a typo here - it is strange that it works when you run it manually. To troubleshoot I would try `aws s3 ls` or other simple aws cli commands in your user-data and add echo lines before them such as `echo "test" && aws --region us-east-1 ec2 describe-instances` to verify if you always get that error. Last but not least add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your user-data to ensure you're in the right shell.

Comment: @paulg it was just a typo here as  didn't copy/paste. I tried aws s3 ls ( after giving ListBucket permission and i have the same error when calling it. And yes, i did an echo output before and after to make sure it's the offender line

Comment: "Unable to locate credentials" means the problem is most likely in your assignment of the instance profile to the EC2 instance. You don't show the creation of an instance profile, or how you are assigning it to the instance anywhere in your question.

Comment: @MarkB I added that to the question

Comment: Difficult to troubleshoot a cloud-init script without the script or the log.

Comment: @Andrey Shouldn't there also be `"s3:ListBucket"` allowed on `"arn:aws:s3:::${var.distro_bucket}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a timing issue where cloud-init is executed before the EC2 profile is set/ready to use. In your cloud-init script, I would make a loop to run a particular AWS cli command or even use the metadata server to retrieve information about the [IAM credentials of the EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials).

As the documentation states, you receive the following response when querying the endpoint `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/iam_role_name`:

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2012-04-26T16:39:16Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "ASIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
  "Token" : "token",
  "Expiration" : "2017-05-17T15:09:54Z"
}
```

So your cloud-init/user-data script could wait until the `Code` attribute equals to `Success` and then proceed with the other operations.

Comment: Is that even possible? I'm not sure it is possible to get the user_data script and into this phase of cloud-init before this. user_data is pulled by cloud-init and run near the end.

Comment: It’s an hypothesis, user has mentioned that the cli commands work once the instance has started so I would discard any IAM/Terraform misconfiguration issues.

Comment: Yeah, it is a reasonable consideration, and I'm not confident it is incorrect. I was genuinely asking; I'm not sure if it is unlikely or impossible based on the implementation.

Comment: I added a delay and retry as you've suggested, and it seems to work fine now. Thank you

Comment: had the same issue, adding `sleep 60` before the first `aws s3 cp` call solved it...